# smallest eigenvalues for linear elasticity

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

I want to compute a few tens of the smallest eigenvalues of a linear system which is a discretization of a linear elasticity. In the presence of additional constraints like Dirichlet boundary conditions, does it help to use the rigid body displacements to deflate the linear system? In that case they might only be approximations of zero eigenmodes, right? Thank you

Comment: Do you mean that you are applying Dirichlet constraints to reduce the number of rigid body modes to something less than six? If so, do you know exactly which rigid body modes remain, e.g. a translation in x and a rotation about z?

Comment: No necessarily. You may want to fix some Dirichlet boundary conditions just to have a specific given configuration in terms of modeling. I'm just curious to know if the rigid body motions are still close to small eigenmodes or not ?Conversely if, for instance, the model can still translate in x, we know for sure that the vector [1,0,0,...,1,0,0] is still an eigenvector.